# Ruby 2: Recognizing decomposed utf8 in XML entities (NFD)

Tags: ruby, xml, utf-8

#### Problem

Problem is simple: I have XML containing this value

`Mu&#x000A8;ller`

This appears to be valid XML format for representing a `u` with an umlaut, like this.

`Müller`

But all the parsers we have tried so far result in `u¨`  -- two distinct characters.

#### Background

This form of unicode (UTF-8) uses two codepoints to represent a single character; and is called Normalized Form Decomposed or NFD, and in binary is `\303\274`.

Most characters can also be represented as a single codepoint and entity, including this case.  The XML could also have included `&uuml;` or `&#252;` or `&#x00FC;` and in binary is `\195\188`.  This is called Normalized Form Composed.  Any of these would work fine.

#### Getting Right to the Question

So I think the question is one of:

- Is there a parser (doesn't seem to be nokogiri) that can detect and normalize to our preferred form?
- Is there a reasonable way for us to reliably detect entities in the NFD form and convert them to the NFC form (or is there something that will do that out there?)

Thanks!

Comment: Ruby is convinced this is two characters as well: `"Mu\u00A8ller"` converts to `"Mu¨ller"`. It may be that NFD isn't supported without a gem like [unf](https://github.com/knu/ruby-unf).

Comment: Character U+00A8 (`DIAERESIS`) _isn’t_ a combining character – it is distinct from U+0308 (`COMBINING DIAERESIS`). (I’ve only just discovered this myself – I don’t know what the use for the non-combining diaeresis is). So it looks like this behaviour is correct and your XML is wrong (should be using `&#x0308;`).

Comment: Something else to be aware of when dealing with combining characters is that many systems (editors, shells etc.) don’t handle them well and may display them as separate characters, even when the actual string is correct. (Browsers seem to do well – at least Chrome does).

Comment: @matt Thank you!!  Make your comments an answer so we can mark it resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character you’re using,  U+00A8 (`DIAERESIS`) *isn’t* a combining character – it is distinct from U+0308 (`COMBINING DIAERESIS`). (I’ve only just discovered this myself – I don’t know what the use for the non-combining diaeresis is).

It looks like in this case this behaviour is correct and your XML is wrong (it should be using `&#x0308;` and not `&#x00A8;`).